# mysql_query successful but getting mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource

Tags: php, mysql, sql

The function below will be used to input a Facebook access token into a database.  The user id will already have an associated record so the "acc_tok" field just needs to be updated.

For some reason even though the $_result value holds "1" and the function echoes out "Successful!", a warning is appearing that says:

"Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given".  Does anyone know why it appears that the query was successful but is only returning a boolean and not something the mysql_fetch_array can work with?  Thanks for reading

```
function setUserAccessToken($_uid, $_accTok){
        $sql = "UPDATE `user_core` SET `acc_tok`=$_accTok WHERE `id` = $_uid";
        $_result = mysql_query($sql) or die($sql."<br/><br/>".mysql_error());
        echo $_result;
        if ($_result) {
        echo ("Successful!");
            $_resultArray = mysql_fetch_array($_result);
            print_r($_resultArray);
        } else {
            echo ("Failed!");
        }
}
```

Comment: It may not help answer your question, but you should stop using `mysql_*` functions. They're being deprecated. Instead use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) (supported as of PHP 5.1) or [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) (supported as of PHP 4.1). If you're not sure which one to use, [read this article](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/pdo-vs-mysqli-which-should-you-use/).

Comment: What does `var_dump($_result)` give you?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're doing an `UPDATE` query, there are no rows to fetch from the result, hence a boolean value from [`mysql_query()`](http://php.net/mysql_query) and not a resource.

From [the manual](http://php.net/mysql_query):

> For other type of SQL statements, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, DROP, etc,
>   mysql_query() returns TRUE on success or FALSE on error.